# XQuery Expression in Soapui

Tags: regex, xquery, wildcard, soapui

I am trying to write an XQuery in SOAPUI to validate an XML response. What I want to do is use a "where" to see if something equals something else with a wildcard. Basically like this.

```
<Result>
{
for $x in //ns3:Building
where $x/ns3:BuildingNumber/text()='JJJ*'     <--- This is my problem
return <Value>{$x/ns3:BuildingNumber/text()}</Value>
}
</Result>
```

I have taken out the namespaces for simplicity but I'm sure all of it works.

When I replace the where with something literal like the following, it works:

```
where $x/ns3:BuildingNumber/text()=JJJ1245
```

I need some kind of wildcard though but I'm not sure how or if it's done in this instance. All missions that start with JJJ. I have tried Regex and others like this but none work:

'JJJ*'
'^JJJ.'
'JJJ.*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `matches()` for regex:

```
where matches($x/ns3:BuildingNumber, '^JJJ.*')
```

Also, be careful with `text()` - usually you want `string()`. [This article](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell) offers a very good explanation.

Comment: One final question, Is there a function for notmatches? If I want to return anything that doesn't start with JJJ? Or would I have to make my regex in that fashion?

Comment: It will be a bit more work, but `analyze-string()` will give you access to the non-matches.

Comment: I see, thanks. I've also noticed that I can do                    where matches($x/ns3:BuildingNumber, 'JJJ.*') = false()